# Android Logcat error - after a 'App has stopped' error message

Tags: android, cordova, runtime-error, adb

I am working on an app built using Cordova, when I build the app and run this on a phone it appears to work fine for a number of minutes however it seems to crash after a few minutes of constant usage.

Using the ADB Logcat command I have managed to retrieve the following error, can anyone suggest more of how this can be fixed to prevent this error happening again? I can see it mentions memory - is there anything I can to improve the memory usage?

I used the following command to get the data, is there a better way to locate the data?

```
adb logcat *:EF

Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1, fault addr 0xa07f9176 in tid 12010 (Chrome_InProcRe)
03-23 15:13:47.675   452   452 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-23 15:13:47.675   452   452 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'samsung/kccat6xx/kccat6:6.0.1/MMB29M/G901FXXS1CQB4:user/release-keys'
03-23 15:13:47.675   452   452 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
03-23 15:13:47.675   452   452 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
03-23 15:13:47.675   452   452 F DEBUG   : pid: 11981, tid: 12010, name: Chrome_InProcRe  >>> com.ccmycc.ccmycc <<<
03-23 15:13:47.675   452   452 F DEBUG   : signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1 (ILL_ILLOPC), fault addr 0xa07f9176
03-23 15:13:47.705   452   452 F DEBUG   :     r0 9dda3964  r1 03e91000  r2 074e1000  r3 04000000
03-23 15:13:47.705   452   452 F DEBUG   :     r4 a2c14f44  r5 03c8d000  r6 00000000  r7 00000000
03-23 15:13:47.705   452   452 F DEBUG   :     r8 03c92000  r9 00000000  sl 03c8c400  fp a2046c91
03-23 15:13:47.705   452   452 F DEBUG   :     ip a2be7ac4  sp 9dda3960  lr a07f9177  pc a07f9176  cpsr 28030030
03-23 15:13:47.705   452   452 F DEBUG   :
03-23 15:13:47.705   452   452 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
03-23 15:13:47.705   452   452 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00281176  /data/app/com.google.android.webview-2/lib/arm/libwebviewchromium.so
03-23 15:13:47.705   452   452 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 00281173  /data/app/com.google.android.webview-2/lib/arm/libwebviewchromium.so
03-23 15:13:49.065   452   452 F DEBUG   :
03-23 15:13:49.065   452   452 F DEBUG   : Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_08
03-23 15:13:49.065   452   452 E DEBUG   : AM write failed: Broken pipe
03-23 15:13:49.065   452   452 E         : ro.product_ship = true
03-23 15:13:49.065   452   452 E         : ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
03-23 15:13:49.065   452   452 E         : sys.mobilecare.preload = false
03-23 15:13:49.075  3738  3738 E audit   : type=1701 msg=audit(1490282029.075:467): auid=4294967295 uid=10258 gid=10258 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 pid=12010 comm="Chrome_InProcRe" reason="memory violation" sig=4
03-23 15:13:49.175   409   409 E lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/11981/oom_score_adj; errno=22
```

Full Log in the gist below :-

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/061a758ab592897a8cb26ec0efed4d6a

Comment: Check the tomstone file that was created, it may contain the info you need.